# Number of votes I have made

Tags: discussion

The way to earn 'Civic Duty' `badge` is to have Voted 300 or more times. Is there any way to find how many votes I have already made?

Comment: It is in your profile summary (not the votes section amusingly) and right at the bottom of the page above the footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section Shree references shows the votes you placed on each individual question and answer, which arguably may not be that helpful if you're trying to figure out how far you are from the Civic Duty badge. If you want to just see the totals, just look for a panel that looks like this at the bottom right section of your user profile, as suggested by Jamal:

[image: Votes on Meta]

You can also see the total votes cast by any user by looking at the bottom right section of his or her user profile.

Answer (score 4):

Better option is just go to [any review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats). There you can see the Civic Duty badge progress bar by hovering on the green progress bar.

> [image]

Comment: This is actually the better answer. It's geared specifically towards badges, and you can also view the progress on other badges without having to hunt down all of the details in separate places.

Answer (score 2):

In your profile page you get all your voted history.

[image: Votes]